# PHP Display None?

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to hide the "topbar" if user is logged in.
Example: http://prntscr.com/chcwhl

My code at the moment is:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'woohoo_add_auth_links', 10 , 2 );
function woohoo_add_auth_links( $items, $args )
{
    if( $args->theme_location == 'topmenu' )
    {
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            echo '<style>#topbar { display:none;}</style>';
        }
        elseif ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
            $items .= '<li><a href="'. site_url('wp-login.php') .'">Log In</a></li>';
            $items .= '<li><a href="'. site_url('wp-login.php?action=register') .'">Register</a></li>';
        }
    }
    return $items;
}
```

I'm sure that the topbar is `<div class="topbar">` so I'm a little confused why it's not hiding...

Comment: better (security, speed, reliability) to exclude it in php than to send it to the browser to then just hide it.

Comment: can you please provide a PHP example so i can get a better understanding of what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

The `#` means ID.
You can fix this by either using:

```
<div id="topbar">
```

Or:

```
echo '<style>.topbar { display:none;}</style>';
```

A `#` is css for ID, and a `.` is css for class.

Comment: I've used # in my code and it won't work?
I also tried with a . but that doesn't seem to work either

Comment: you cant dump css rules anywhere on the page. they need to be in the head

Comment: F12. Can you see console log error? at the browser.